# cannot get length of 2d array having array names in it

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I cant get length of 2d array having other array names inside it. Like..

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = { 23, 4, 6 };
int[][] ab = { a, b };
int r = ab.GetLength(1);
```

Comment: Take a look at [Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetLength(1) is intended for 2D arrays, you have a jagged array (array of arrays) and all your arrays only have a single dimension. As such, you cannot have 1 as an argument to GetLength

I would, for example:

```
int r = ab[1].Length; // the length of the 23,4,6 array
```

Also:

```
ab.Length //it is 2, there are two 1D arrays in ab
```

We call it jagged because it doesn't have to have the same length array in each slot:

```
ab[0] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
ab[1] = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
```